# Wordpress Custom Post Type Sort by Title Last Word ASC

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-order-by, custom-post-type

I am taking a custom post type and trying to display it by the last word of the post title. From there, I want to pass in a variable of what letter I would like to see (eg "starts_with" = "A") in the WP_Query. Lastly, I want to display this in ASC order. From this code, how do I display in ASC order?

```
function dp_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $starts_with = $query->get( 'starts_with' );

    if ( $starts_with ) {
        $last_name = "RIGHT($wpdb->posts.post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE($wpdb->posts.post_title)) - 1)";

        $where .= " AND $last_name LIKE '$starts_with%'";
    }

    return $where;
}


add_filter( 'posts_where', 'dp_posts_where', 10, 2 );
```

Please advise! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Orderby Last Word In Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416217/wordpress-orderby-last-word-in-title)

Comment: Hi Katelyn, it looks like at least part of you question may be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416217/wordpress-orderby-last-word-in-title?rq=1.  Take a look and see if you can find some guidance there.  If not, can you clarify what from there doesn't work for your use case?  It may better help someone help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function my_movies_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'my-movie' ) ) {
        $orderby = "SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, ' ', -1) ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_movies_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
```